# Calculating standardized regression coefficients for a mediation model

Tags: r, regression, coefficients

When conducting a mediation analysis, I would like to obtain standardized coefficients for each path, but I'm unable to do so. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
subdata <- subset(data, select=c(psychological, physical, stress))


install.packages("mediation")
install.packages("psych")
library("psych")
library("mediation")

me.out1 <- psych::mediate(y ="physical", m ="psychological", x ="stress", data = subdata)# 매개효과 분석


coef_val <- coef(me.out1)

coef_val
```